# override navigation of datagridview using enter key is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, keydown, onkeydown

I want to modify the current behaviour of datagridview related to navigation on enter key. Current behaviour is to jump to the next row and same column, and I want to jump to the next column and same row so I have implemented the following keyDown event:

```
    private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        int numCols = this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
        int numRows = this.dataGridView1.RowCount;
        DataGridViewCell currCell = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell;
        if (currCell.ColumnIndex == numCols - 1)
        {
            if (currCell.RowIndex < numRows - 1)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[0, currCell.RowIndex + 1];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[currCell.ColumnIndex + 1, currCell.RowIndex];
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the above event is not being raised on enter key pressed despite I have subscribed to the datagridview keydown event correctly by doing:

```
this.dataGridView1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(dataGridView1_KeyDown);
```

Hence that, the current behaviour on enter key pressed continues being the default: next row and same column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried KeyUp? I would guess the default behavior to move to another row would occurr on KeyUp, give it a test, press enter and hold it and see if it moves down a column or if it waits for you to keyup. Also could be keypress, might test each of these to see because your event might be firing before the default event behavior.

Also, are you *certain* the code which has the event subscription is executing? If it's in the standard place I would assume so, but I'm just throwing out there the possibility that you have that line placed in a method which does not execute just in case.

Comment: Yes, I have tried KeyUp and also KeyPress, but it does not work. If I press enter and hold it, it moves to the next rows and same column successively until it reaches the last row. This behaviour is the same for all events, keyUp, KeyDown and KeyPress. Also, I have checked that the line in which I do the subscription to the event is executed correctly but despite subscription is done correctly, the event KeyDown, KeyUp or KeyPress never fires. However, in the same place where I do this subscription, I do other subscriptions such as cellParsing and this fires.

Comment: Hi again, I have discovered what is happening: KeyUp, KeyDown and KeyPress only are fired for datagridview columns of type: datagridviewcheckboxcolumn and datagridviewbuttoncolumn but not for other types such as datagridviewcomboboxcolumn, datagridviewtextboxcolumn or custom columns. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Perhaps the event needs to be attached to the actual column that is selected rather than the gridview, could be the keydown is being handled at the cell level.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void dataGridView2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        e.Handled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("{tab}");
    }
 }
```